# How to define functions using $Z_2$ coefficients and $Z_N$ variables, e.g, realizing $1+1=0$?

Tags: function-construction, algebraic-manipulation, variable-definitions, algebra, boolean-computation

A minimal example is to realize the following:

$x+x = (1+1)x = 0$, and $x^{N+1}y^{N+1}=xy$,

where $N$ is a given positive integer.

Comment: Do you really want $x^2 = x$?

Comment: @user293787, that was indeed a mistake... It should be $x^N=1$ for a given positive integer N. Revised the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1.** One could use

```
z2reduce[expr_]:=With[{vars=Variables[expr]},
  FromCoefficientRules[CoefficientRules[expr,vars]
    /.Rule[pow_,coeff_]:>Rule[Mod[pow,2],Mod[coeff,2]],vars]];
```

Examples:

```
7 // z2reduce
(* 1 *)

3*x^5 // z2reduce
(* x *)

-x*y^3+y^5 // z2reduce
(* y+x y *)
```

---

If I understand the updated question and comment, OP also wants to allow to set say $x^2 = 1$ and $y^3 = 1$ (or some other choice of exponents). One can use

```
znreduce[ns_][expr_]:=With[{vars=Variables[expr]},
  FromCoefficientRules[CoefficientRules[expr,vars]
    /.Rule[pow_,coeff_]:>Rule[MapThread[Mod,{pow,ns}],Mod[coeff,2]],vars]];
```

Examples:

```
-x*y^3+y^5 // znreduce[{2,2}] (* same as above *)
(* y+x y *)

-x*y^3+y^5 // znreduce[{2,3}] (* here y^3 = 1 *)
(* x+y^2 *)
```

---

**Method 2.** Another solution is [`PolynomialReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce.html). Examples:

```
Last[PolynomialReduce[-x*y^3+y^5,{x^2-1,y^2-1},{x,y},Modulus->2]]
(* y+x y *)

Last[PolynomialReduce[-x*y^3+y^5,{x^2-1,y^3-1},{x,y},Modulus->2]]
(* x+y^2 *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is it possible to genralize it to cases with two (or multiple) variables? Namely, how to specify rules for individual members in the list $vars$ ($x,y$ in your third example)?

Comment: It perfectly realizes what I want!